# Constrain an animated ball's position on the screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying out some simple animation, and have followed a tutorial for a basic bouncing ball.

How can I constrain where the ball bounces using my own set of co-ordinates rather than the whole screen? The code I'm using from the tutorial randomly picks co-ordinates from the whole of the screen, and I would like to set its co-ordinates so it only bounces in a small square in the middle of the screen, and not go out of those bounds.

.m

```
 int ballx, bally;
 ///////

 ballx = arc4random() % 320;   

 bally = arc4random() % 480; 

 //////////


-(void)movetheball { 
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"MovingTheBallAround" context: nil];   

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    myball.frame =  CGRectMake(ballx, bally,myball.frame.size.width,myball.frame.size.height);  
    [UIView commitAnimations];   

}
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(SEL)aSelector {  

    if (finished) {  

        // set new coordinate for ballx and bally  

        ballx = arc4random() % 320; 

        bally = arc4random() % 480;   



        [self movetheball];  

    }
```

I've looked on SO, but I couldn't find anything similar, except the following:

```
ballx.center = CGPointMake(320/2, [self randNumBetween:-50:-100]);
```

which I tried to adapt without much success.  I have not got a huge amount of experience with programming so I'm not sure if I'm way off base with that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ballx = arc4random() % 320; 

bally = arc4random() % 480;
```

These are, as you've noticed, the lines where you set the new coordinates of the ball, and these two variables are just numbers. They don't have components called `center`, nor are they `CGPoint`s, so although you're on the right track with your proposed modification, you're making things too complicated for yourself.

The part that you may not understand is the `%` sign; this is the ["modulus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator. In simple terms, it limits the number on its left side to be less than the number on its right.

Notice that `320` and `480` happen to be the width and height of the whole screen, and observe that you are assigning the results of the modulo operations -- using that width and height -- to the variables representing your ball's position.

Hopefully that's enough of a hint.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the hint may be to subtle for me.  I feel like I need to give it a variable between to points on the x and y axis, this does not work though: ballx = arc4random() % 140,240; when I manually set my bounds just seems to go off my target area as its still picking a random co ordinate that may be out my area

Comment: You're very close. Each of those variables is one portion of the ball's postion. You don't want to put both of those new constraints (140 and 240) on the same line, but use one for each assignment.

Comment: Also, you are getting a random number between 0 and the constraint you specify, which means the ball will be in a rectangle whose corner is at the corner of the screen. If you want to move that rectangle to the center of the screen, you will have to add an offset to the x and y values after generating them: `ballx = arc4random() % 140; ballx += 80;`, for example.

Comment: Aha! Now the penny has dropped, thank you very much for your help, and helping me get there myself, I shall save that in my code snippets for future reference.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to modify following part come up with the logic to have you bounds set for whatever view window necessary.

```
ballx = arc4random() % 320;   
bally = arc4random() % 480;
```

Or you can create the UIView of specific size and place it into your UIViewController wherever you want by [Self.view addsubview:constrainedView ] and then you can add ball in that view. But again you will have to change arc4random() % x;  where x is width or height of the UIView.